# How to condition an if else statement when the button is clicked and video is playing

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, html5-video

I have a three buttons, Trailer, Movies and Movies Ads. I want to play the video dynamically, like when I clicked the button Trailer, then the video trailer must shown, when I clicked the button Movies, then the movie video must shown, and when I clicked the movie ads it must be shown again.

**My Buttons**

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" id="trailer">Trailer</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" id="movies">Movies</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" id="movieads">Movie Ads</button>
```

What I have right now under the video as you can see is a simple pseudo code which concludes my logic, is there any way to make this syntax achievable and working? thank you. please see my code below.

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container" id='container'>
         <div id="getdata" style='display: none;'>
            <div class="overlay">
                <br><br><br><br><br>
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="text-center col-md-12">
                      <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: rgba(42, 44, 45, 0.9); color: #71777f">
                        <h3>Passenger Announcement is Going On.</h3>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
              </div>    
            </div>
         </div>
----------------------PSEUDOCODE HERE-----------------------------------
         <?php 

          if (trailer == clicked) {
            echo '<video controls playsinline id="player" width="100%">
                <source src="./inflightapp/storage/app/public/trailer_videos/<?php echo ''.$row2['trailer_video'].''; ?>" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
            </video>';
          }else if(movies == clicked){
            echo '<video controls playsinline id="player" width="100%">
            <source src="./inflightapp/storage/app/public/movie_videos/<?php echo ''.$row2['movies_video'].''; ?>" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
            </video>';
          }else if(moviesAds ==clicked){
            echo '<video controls playsinline id="player" width="100%">
            <source src="./inflightapp/storage/app/public/movie_ads/<?php echo ''.$row2['movies_video'].''; ?>" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
            </video>';
          }

          ?>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need to send this url from server then you need to use Ajax  for this you're adding click handler in JavaScript fetch the url from server and inject it into a page.

Comment: @jcubic , is there any other way to do without ajax/

Comment: You can hide all the video tags and show the one you need in javascript on click.

Comment: @jcubic can you help me with the code please? im not that familiar with javascript :( thank you..

Comment: just to clarify, when you clicked the button a modal will appear and the video will play inside that modal right?

Comment: @KarlGuevarra , yepppp.. that's it :) i hope you can help me with this. thank you sir

Comment: @KarlGuevarra do you have solution? i just need to make it dynamically played when any of the button was clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, put all videos into html and only show them on click.

HTML,PHP:

```
<ul class="buttons">
  <li><button target=".videos .trailer">Trailer</button></li>
  <li><button target=".videos .movie">Movie</button></li>
</ul>
<div class="videos">
  <div class="trailer">
     <video controls playsinline id="player" width="100%">
         <source src="./inflightapp/storage/app/public/trailer_videos/<?= $row2['trailer_video'] ?>" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
     </video>
   </div>
   <div class="movie">
       <video controls playsinline id="player" width="100%">
            <source src="./inflightapp/storage/app/public/movie_videos/<?= $row2['movies_video'] ?>" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
       </video>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.buttons [target]'));
var videos = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.videos > div'));
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     videos.forEach(function(video) {
        video.style.display = 'none';
     });
     document.querySelector(button.getAttribute('target')).style.display = 'block';
  });
});
```

css:

```
.videos > div {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: ill try it thanks for the answer and help ill analyze your answer :)